# send correct header with dropzone

Tags: ajax, laravel, vue.js, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone http://www.dropzonejs.com/ but as a vuejs component: https://github.com/rowanwins/vue-dropzone

I am also using laravel which has something called csrf-token which is supposed to be sent with each request to the server so that server can validate the request as legit or not.

I need to send this token when uploading pictures with dropzone. Laravel documentation suggests doing:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

```
Then, once you have created the meta tag, you can instruct a library like
jQuery to automatically add the token to all request headers. This provides
simple, convenient CSRF protection for your AJAX based applications:

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

By default, the resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js file registers the value of
the  csrf-token meta tag with the Axios HTTP library. If you are not using
this library, you will need to manually configure this behavior for your application.
```

So inside my dropzone component mounted I placed this code:

```
    mounted () {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
```

when my dropzone uploads the files to the server I get an exception from the server since csrf-token is missing. I also inspected headers being sent to server and the token was not there.

My question, is dropzone actually using ajax to send the pictures? If yes then why is not code above adding correct headers, if its not using ajax to send headers then how can I set correct header?

Comment: Where did you store the `csrf-token` ?

Comment: inside my layout blade file

Comment: is it in HTML meta tag?

Comment: yeah: <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

Comment: I tried this inside dropzone.vue mount: console.log('token:' + $('meta[name="crsf-token"]').attr('content'))... it prints undefined any idea why?

Comment: i have not worked much with laravel, so can you setup the csrf-token using `csrf_token()` in the data option?

Comment: http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-headers I tried that but it sets no header, wonder why

Answer (score 2):

Dropzone vue component has headers as a prop. You need to set this prop with headers you want dropzone to send to server and it will work.